# jQuery if statement not working inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, each

Im having trouble figuring out what the problem is here. It doesnt work when i use **'#account-funding-'+i** in the IF statement but does work with **'#account-funding-0'**. I need to be able to loop through the array of unknown amount of objects. What am i doing wrong?

**HTML**
* There can be X number of .funding-content div's on the page. Every ID with a -0 will increment from the js

```
<form id="accountform" name="accountForm">

 <div class="funding-content funding-selected-0">
   <div class="container">
    <h3>Funding for [account selected]</h3>

     <div class="funding-type-transfer" id="funding-type-transfer-0">

       <div class="form-inputs">
         <div class="lx-grid lx-grid--gutters">
           <div class="lx-grid__cell lx-grid__cell--1-2--above-md">
             <label for="account-funding-0">Routing Number</label>
             <input id="account-funding-0" type="text" maxlength="9">
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

**Doesnt Work:**

```
var amountOfAccounts = $( '#account-form .funding-content' ).length;

for ( i = 0; i <= amountOfAccounts; i++ ) {

    if ( $( '#account-funding-'+i ).val() == '' ) {
        document.getElementById( 'account-funding-'+i ).setCustomValidity( 'Routing Number is a required field.' );
    }
}
```

**Works:**

```
var amountOfAccounts = $( '#account-form .funding-content' ).length;

for ( i = 0; i <= amountOfAccounts; i++ ) {

    if ( $( '#account-funding-0' ).val() == '' ) {
        document.getElementById( 'account-funding-'+i ).setCustomValidity( 'Routing Number is a required field.' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your HTML also

Comment: `'#account-funding-'+i` does result in `'#account-funding-0'` so I feel like this is starting to become an XY problem.  What are you seeing that is not working?

Comment: It *should* work.  With that said, it's possible that the page isn't fully loaded , which is causing errors.  Hard to diagnose until you post the HTML

Comment: You'll have to show the HTML, but the thing that immediately jumps out is that you're doing `i = 0; i <= amountOfAccounts; i++`. Normally it would be `i = 0; i < amountOfAccounts; i++` or `i = 1; i <= amountOfAccounts; i++`. If you use `val` on an empty jQuery set, you'll get the value `undefined`. (Whether that's a problem depends a lot on `do something`.)

Comment: Having a series of `id`s like that is an anti-pattern though. Just loop through the jQuery set returned by `$("#account-form .funding-content")`.

Comment: try to define a new string before comparison, `let x = '#account-funding-'+i` then `if ( $(x).val() == '' )`

Comment: It's quite hard to say what's wrong. However, my gut feeling is it's [the old closures inside loop chestnut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: The code works fine. The error is somewhere else. https://jsfiddle.net/n803tc8x/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder...thank you for your advise. It looks like it was something as simple as changing <= to <

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you aren't getting the right `id` in the loop?
if Yes, set your loop variable to be created as a `let`, so it is not hoisted and is block scope, for this loop.

Also, to loop through correct number of elements, use `<` instead of `<=`.

See if this helps you. (or maybe I understood it completely wrong, if so, I can made some adjustment or delete this answer)

```js
var amountOfAccounts = $('#account-form .funding-content').length;

for (let i = 0; i < amountOfAccounts; i++ ) {
    var elemValue = $( '#account-funding-'+i ).val();
    if ( elemValue == '' || elemValue == null) {
        console.log('empty value');
    }else{
        console.log(elemValue);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="account-form">
 <input value="abc" class='funding-content' id="account-funding-0">
  <input value="" class='funding-content' id="account-funding-1">
 <input value="def" class='funding-content' id="account-funding-2">
 <input value="" class='funding-content' id="account-funding-3">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer along with @T.J Crowder ended up fixing the issue. I just needed to change <= to <

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, the index is not matching an element somewhere. But, you don't need to do it like this. JQuery provides an **[`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** method to loop through the objects so you don't have to worry about any of that:

```
$( '#account-form .funding-content' ).each(function(index, element){
   if(element.val() !== ""){
      // Do something
   }
});
```